# Use yeoman as CLI

Tags: javascript, yeoman-generator

Is it possible to create a Yeoman generator, that can act like Angular CLI ?

Example:
I can create an Angular app using the CLI and  sometime in the future I could extend the project with a component using the CLI again.

Can I create a yeoman generator that can scaffold a project (yo myproject) and sometime in the future i will add more files and configurations to the project.

Can yeoman generator do that? If no, then what can do it.

Comment: I have this same question. Can Yeoman FountainJS be used like Angular CLI to generate additional components, directives, services etc, or do these modules need to be created manually? I'm creating an Angular 1.6 projects for testing different features of Angular and want something that I can get up and running quickly. Angular CLI only seems to support Angular 2 styling and even though that's where Angular would like us to go, not all of my apps are in Angular 2 and I don't want to change that fact at this time.